# Navigation in wicket - AjaxPagingNavigator

Tags: java, wicket

I faced the problem with AjaxPagingNavigator. The problem is that when I press "go to next" or "go to previous" instead of moving to the next or previous page, it jumps 1 page. For example if I am on the 5th page and press "go to next" instead of moving to the 6th page, it jumps to the 7th. Can you assist me in solving this. Where did it go wrong? Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class OnlineBankAjaxPagingNavigator extends AjaxPagingNavigator {
    PagingNavigation currentNavigation = null;
    Map<String, Link<?>> firstLastMap = new HashMap();
    Map<String, Link<?>> prevNextMap = new HashMap();

    public OnlineBankAjaxPagingNavigator(String id, IPageable pageable) {
        super (id, pageable);
    }

    public OnlineBankAjaxPagingNavigator(String id, IPageable pageable, IPagingLabelProvider labelProvider) {
        super (id, pageable, labelProvider);
    }

    // forming navigation pages "first", "last"
    protected Link<?> newPagingNavigationLink(String id, IPageable pageable, int pageNumber)
    {
        Link<?> ret = null;
        if (firstLastMap.containsKey(id))
            ret = firstLastMap.get(id);
        else {
            AjaxPagingNavigationLink navCont = new AjaxPagingNavigationLink(id + "Cont", pageable, pageNumber);

            // add css for enable/disable link
            long pageIndex = pageable.getCurrentPage() + pageNumber;
            navCont.add(new AttributeModifier("class", new OnlineBankAjaxPageLinkCssModel(pageable,pageIndex, "navigator_bg")));

            navCont.add(new AjaxPagingNavigationLink(id, pageable, pageNumber));
            ret = navCont;
            firstLastMap.put(id,ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // forming navigation pages "prev", "next"
    protected Link<?> newPagingNavigationIncrementLink(String id, IPageable pageable, int increment)
    {
        Link<?> ret = null;
        if (prevNextMap.containsKey(id))
            ret = prevNextMap.get(id);
        else {
            AjaxPagingNavigationIncrementLink navCont = new AjaxPagingNavigationIncrementLink(id+ "Cont", pageable, increment);

            // add css for enable/disable link
            long pageIndex = pageable.getCurrentPage() + increment;
            navCont.add(new AttributeModifier("class",
               new OnlineBankAjaxPageLinkIncrementCssModel(pageable, pageIndex)));

            // change original wicket-link, so that it always generates href
            navCont.add(new AjaxPagingNavigationIncrementLink(id, pageable, increment));
            prevNextMap.put(id, navCont);
            ret = navCont;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // forming navigation pages - 1,2,3 ...
    protected PagingNavigation newNavigation(IPageable pageable, IPagingLabelProvider labelProvider) {
        PagingNavigation tmp;
        String id;

        if (currentNavigation==null) {
            tmp = super.newNavigation(pageable, labelProvider);
            id = tmp.getId();
            tmp = null;

            currentNavigation =  new AjaxPagingNavigation (id, pageable, labelProvider) {
                @Override
                protected LoopItem newItem(int iteration) {
                    LoopItem item = super.newItem(iteration);

                    // add css for enable/disable link
                    long pageIndex = getStartIndex() + iteration;
                    item.add(new AttributeModifier("class",
                        new OnlineBankAjaxPageLinkCssModel(pageable,
                                pageIndex, "navigator_active")));
                    return item;
                }
            };
        }

        return currentNavigation;
    }
};
```

And html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <style>

        .navigator_bg {
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma Arial;
            font-style: normal;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

        .navigatorBgDigit{
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

        .navigator_active{
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma Arial;
            font-style: normal;
            background-color: #236B98;
            color: #AFEEEE;
        }

        a.navigatorLink:link {
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

        a.navigatorLink:visited {
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

        a.navigatorLink:hover {
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

        a.navigatorLink:active {
            font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #00395D;
        }

    </style>
    <table border='0'>
    <tr class="navigator_bg">
        <td width="18px" height="18px" align="center" valign="middle" wicket:id="firstCont" class="navigator_bg">&nbsp;<a class="navigatorLink" wicket:id="first" href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="18px" height="18px" align="center" valign="middle" wicket:id="prevCont" class="navigator_bg">&nbsp;<a class="navigatorLink" wicket:id="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="18px" height="18px" align="center" valign="middle" wicket:id="navigation" class="navigatorBgDigit"><a wicket:id="pageLink" href="#" class="navigatorLink"><span wicket:id="pageNumber">1</span></a></td>
        <td width="18px" height="18px" align="center" valign="middle" wicket:id="nextCont" class="navigator_bg">&nbsp;<a class="navigatorLink" wicket:id="next" href="#">&gt;</a>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="18px" height="18px" align="center" valign="middle" wicket:id="lastCont" class="navigator_bg">&nbsp;<a class="navigatorLink" wicket:id="last" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does debugging tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Following answer is not acceptable for this question. See UPDATE section for right answer.*

I faced with this problem while migrating to Wicket 7. Code, that was migrated, had no changes, but didn't work properly. There was not only the problem described above. If I clicked any navigation page link - "Access denied" page is occured. After some researches, I have realized, that there are **two same events** sending when some link is clicked, so you incrementing page two times, or go to page, then link, which was clicked dissapears and second request trying to access this dissapeared link, so "Access denied" page is occured.

I really don't know if this a bug, or I'm doing something wrong, but I have not found any information about this problem. So, I have implmeneted a workaround for paging links.

If you look at `AjaxPagingNavigationIncrementLink` and `AjaxPagingNavigationLink` markup after page is rendered - you see, that such components have something like `href="./?3-8.ILinkListener-..."` which calls link listener. If we remove this `href` source, then component will work properly and execute only one ajax request. So, override `onComponentTag` method for all occurances of `AjaxPagingNavigationIncrementLink` and `AjaxPagingNavigationLink` with such code:

```
/**
 * Overridden to workaround wicket 7 behavior, which proccessed an error, when ajax navigation is used.
 */
@Override
protected void onComponentTag ( final ComponentTag tag )
{
    super.onComponentTag ( tag );
    if ( !Strings.isEmpty ( tag.getAttribute ( "href" ) ) ) // checking if href is not null or empty with org.apache.wicket.util.string.Strings class.
    {
        tag.put ( "href", "" ); //removing any contents of the href option.
    }
}
```

Note, that `AjaxPagingNavigation` also has method `newPagingNavigationLink(...)`.

Note 2, that in Wicket 6 links also have `href` option and it works properly.

Anyway, hope this helps and wicket developers will comment this answer for better understanding :).

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, as it turned out this answer does not connected with a question :).

The problem is with implementation of `newPagingNavigationLink` and `newPagingNavigationIncrementLink` methods.

In this methods you are placing one link to another, and this is produce your strange behavior. So, you must get rid of that and return simple `AjaxPagingNavigationLink` and increment link. You can add your behavior to this links.

I think that you want to update your containers styles via `OnlineBankAjaxPageLinkIncrementCssModel` but you can't place such links in any container(because thay actually added in `PagingNavigator#onInitialize` method). So you can update only this link with this behavior, or use javascript. There is another option to do what you want, but it is about another question (hint: you must override `onInitialize` and `add` methods ).

Also, why do you decide to cache links into `HashMap`s? There is no benefits to do so, as such links created only once for a `OnlineBankAjaxPagingNavigator` lifecycle. So you can remove this caching too.

Comment: It did remove href part but it didn't change the functionality. It still jumps 2 pages. Is it possible to be because of onclick part?

Comment: You can try, but in my rendered markup there is no onclick option. Wait for a while, I will try your code. And could you say which wicket version do you use?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, and it is absolutely not connected to answer, that I have posted XD. It is about your implementation, where you add AjaxPagingNavigationLink to another AjaxPagingNavigationLink and same for increment link. You can't do such things. I will update this answer

Comment: ty, will modify it. The problem is that we are currently working on a project and it is not my code. I just received it to fix. It is like cleaning after someone who didn't pay attention. Thank you!

Comment: It's my pleasure. And yes, I think, you don't need to override onComponentTag method. :)